# Racket eof-object read from input port

Tags: io, scheme, racket

I tried to read string from an input-port in Racket, but no matter what API functions I used to read (`read`, `read-string`, `read-bytes` etc), the return value of those functions was never equal `eof-object`.

```
(define (some_process inp)
 (begin
    (let ([c (read-string 1 inp)])
      (if (eof-object? c)
          (begin
            (display "EOF \n")
            #f)
          (if (equal? c "\n")
              (begin 
                (display "NEWLINE \n"))
              (some_process inp))))))
```

The `c` can never be an `eof-object`?

If you display what `c` is, it is always a newline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read reference:

- [read-char](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Byte_and_String_Input.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._read-char%29%29): "Reads a single character from `in` – which may involve reading several bytes to UTF-8-decode them into a character. **If no bytes are available before an end-of-file, then `eof` is returned.**"
- [read-string](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Byte_and_String_Input.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._read-string%29%29): "Returns a string containing the next `amt` characters from `in`. **If no characters are available before an end-of-file, then `eof` is returned.**"

Examples:

```
> (read-char (open-input-string "char"))
#\c
> (read-string 50 (open-input-string "the string"))
"the string"
>
```

But if there are no character(s) in the buffer, you'll get `eof`:

```
> (read-char (open-input-string ""))
#<eof>
> (read-string 50 (open-input-string ""))
#<eof>
```

I think you just want to read some amount of characters in a loop and do something with them. If so, the solution would look something along the lines of:

```
(define (another-process inp)
  (let ([c (read-char inp)])
    (if (eof-object? c)
        (begin (display "==== EOF ====") (newline))
        (begin (display c) (newline)
               (another-process inp)))))
```

Example:

```
> (another-process (open-input-string "OK"))
O
K
==== EOF ====
> (another-process (open-input-string ""))
==== EOF ====
>
```

Notice a second call to `another-process` with an empty line, it detects `eof` immediately and exits the loop.

**EDIT:**
In case you need to check if the read character is newline:

```
(define (process-moo inp)
  (let ([c (read-char inp)])
    (cond
      ((eof-object? c)
       (display "==== EOF ====") (newline))
      ((eq? c #\newline)
       (newline) (display "---- NEWLINE ----") (newline)
       (process-moo inp))
      (else
       (display c)
       (process-moo inp)))))
```

Example:

```
> (call-with-input-string "Hello\nhumans\n!" process-moo)
Hello
---- NEWLINE ----
humans
---- NEWLINE ----
!==== EOF ====
>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: BTW, `(another-process (open-input-string "OK"))` is the same as `(call-with-input-string "OK" another-process)`.

Comment: Thanks Yasir~ it is very helpful. Basically, I want to parse a comment in  a file. If the comment is in the end of the line of file, I will not give a newline, but if it is in the middle of a file, e.g. after some code, then I have to emit a newline, so I have a eat-comment process, to eat the comment, but in the process, I need to check whether it ends with a newline, or the comment is just at the last line of the file. But when I test like my previous coding listed, the code will not execute the eof-object path, but the newline path......

Answer (score 1):

If you are entering your input from the console, try pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (in Unix and MacOSX), or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, then <kbd>Enter</kbd> (in Windows). This will signal the end of the input.